# Delphi - Error on Creating Class Instance within Subroutine

Tags: class, delphi

Delphi XE6.  I have created a class called TBizObject.  It is a very simple class.  (Code fragments below). I have a form, with a "test" button.

```
procedure TMgtForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BizObj1, BizObj2, BizObj3: TBizObj;
begin
// Test Routine
  BizObj1 := TBizObj.Create;
  BizObj2 := TBizObj.Create;
  BizObj3 := TBizObj.Create;
  CreateTest;

  BizObj1.Free;
  BizObj2.Free;
  BizObj3.Free;

end;
```

ASSUME CreateTest is commented out.  The code works fine.  With CreateTest I get an AV.  The createTest routine is nothing more that Create and Free.

```
procedure TMgtForm.CreateTest;
var
  BizObj4: TBizObj;
begin

  BizObj4.Create;
  BizObj4.Free;
end;
```

In short, I can create my class in a main routine (i.e. a button/menu), but I can't have a routine, that calls a routine, which creates my class.

When I drill down into the error, I am getting an AV on the fParenLine.

```
// Constructor
constructor TBizObj.Create;
begin
  inherited;

  // Setup out default Values;
  fParenList := TStringList.Create;
  fUniqueWordList := TStringList.Create;
  fUniqueWordList.Sorted := True;
  fUniqueWordList.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
  fBaseWordList := TStringList.Create;
end;
```

The relevant part of my class definition is as follows.

```
type
  TBizObj = class(TObject)
    // Internal class field definitions - only accessible in this unit   
  private
    fIncomingName: string; // This is the name that is passed in...
    fIncomingNameLength: Integer;
    ...
    fParenList: TStringList; /// TStringList of ALL ParenthesisText, assuming last one will be City and State
    ...
     protected
    // Externally accessible fields and methods
  public
  published
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
```

Application compiles fine...I can create as many BizObj as I want, but only in top level routines. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Just a typo. That happens from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BizObj4.Create;
```

This is the mistake. Create an instance like this:

```
BizObj4 := TBizObj.Create;
```

Notice the difference between the code in `Button1Click` and `CreateTest`. You got it right in the former, but not in the latter.

Comment: Stupid mistake... I know better!  Thanks.